# JS, get the closest previous number from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, shopify

I need to retrieve the closest number from an array, however this number must always use the lower number from the array even if it is not the closest, I need to do this in plain JS, for example :-

```
Input = 499
Array = [100, 250, 500, 1000, 5000]
Answer = 250

Input = 900
Array = [100, 250, 500, 1000, 5000]
Answer = 500
```

EDIT: Ninas solution worked for fining the number however when used in my code I get error :-

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure 'undefined' or 'null'.
```

Usage :-

```
var qtyBreaks = $("#SingleOptionSelector-0>option").map(function() { 
  if ($(this).val() != "sample"){
    return parseInt($(this).val());
  }
});

$('#Quantity-product-template').on('input', function() {
  console.log(getSmaller($(this).val(), qtyBreaks));    
  // qtyBreaks = [100, 250, 500, 1000, 5000]
  // $(this).val = 102 (always number)
});

function getSmaller(value, array) {
  return array.find((v, i, { [i + 1]: next }) => v === value || next > value);
}
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: what if you look for `500` do you want to get `250` or `500`? please add your try.

Comment: Close-voters: This question is on-topic. It is short, concise, and clear. That it doesn't contain a MCVE is irrelevant as it does not express having tried anything.

Comment: so you basically need the biggest number in the list that is still `<=` the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find it by looking to the next value of the array.

```js
function getSmaller(value, array) {
    return array.find((v, i, { [i + 1]: next }) => v === value || next > value);
}

console.log(getSmaller(400, [100, 250, 500, 1000, 5000]));  //  250
console.log(getSmaller(500, [100, 250, 500, 1000, 5000]));  //  500
console.log(getSmaller(5000, [100, 250, 500, 1000, 5000])); // 5000
```

For all smaller values, you could change the condition.

```js
function getSmaller(value, array) {
    return array.find((_, i, { [i + 1]: next }) => next >= value);
}

console.log(getSmaller(400, [100, 250, 500, 1000, 5000]));  //  250
console.log(getSmaller(500, [100, 250, 500, 1000, 5000]));  //  250
console.log(getSmaller(5000, [100, 250, 500, 1000, 5000])); // 1000
```

Comment: Didn't know this syntax. Much cleaner this way.

Comment: Nina thanks, that give's me the correct number however I get an error when used in context, see the question edit.

Comment: @MT, what type is `$(this).val()`? please add a value for this.

Comment: if find is working, you got an array. the third parameter is the array reference and this is destructurable (if that word exists) and it should work. maybe you log the array and have a look to the content, before calling `find`.

Comment: It's working now, if the number is greater than the last number in array I get undefined returned e.g. 10000 should return 5000

Comment: then add `|| next === undefined` in the condition part.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort array in descending order (for this case you can use `Array.reverse()`) and find the first element (`Array.find()`) which is less then or equal to input value.

Hope this helps

```js
var input1 = 499
var array1 = [100, 250, 500, 1000, 5000]

var input2 = 900
var array2 = [100, 250, 500, 1000, 5000]


var output1 = array1.reverse().find(item => item <= input1);

console.log('Output 1: ', output1);

var output2 = array2.reverse().find(item => item <= input2);

console.log('Output 2: ', output2);
```